# Is there a countable "continuous" set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

I am self-taught and I'm trying to learn about topology with the Book of James R. Munkres. In the reading I came across with this Lemma (Lemma 10.2 for tor those who have the book):

" There exists a well-ordered set $A$ having a largest element $\Omega$, such that the section $S_\Omega$ 
 of $A$ by $\Omega$ is uncountable but every other section of $A$ is countable."

The book defines, for a well-ordered set $X$, a section of $X$ by $\alpha$ as the set $S_\alpha=\{x|x\in X \text{ and } x<\alpha\}$

Because the proof is an important part of my doubt, I transcribe it below word by word:

"We begin with an uncountable well-ordered set $B$. Let $C$ be the well-ordered set $\{1,\,2\}\times B$ in the dictionary order; then some section $C$ is uncountable. (Indeed, the section of $C$ by any element of the form $2\times b$ is uncountable.) Let $\Omega$ be the smallest element of $C$ for wich the section of $C$ by $\Omega$ is uncountable. Then let $A$ consist of this section along with the element $\Omega$."

So, this blow my mind and I'm trying to follow the demonstration with a speciic example. I'm thinking like there is nothing in the theorem or in the proof that forbids taking $B=[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$, with the restriction of the usual order (then $B$ is well-ordered). In this way $\Omega$ can't be of the form $(2,b)$, with $b\in[0,\,1]$, because every element of $C$ of the form $(1,\,b')$, with $b'\in[0,\,1]$,  will be smaller.  Then, as the proof goes, there is an element $\Omega=(1,\,b')$, for wich the section $S_{\Omega}$ is uncountable, but for $\Omega'=(1,\,b'')$, with $b''<b'$,  $S_{\Omega'}$ will be countable. So, for me, it sounds like, there is a continuum interval $[0,b'')$ wich is countable, and as far as I know this is impossible. So I think I'm misunderstanding something here.

As always, I thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: On the contrary, you cannot take $B=[0,1]$. This set is far from being well-ordered. In fact, no uncountable subset of the reals is well-ordered by the standard ordering of the reals.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo But...is bounded, then every subset is bounded.

Comment: Does Sec27 perhaps address this?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Isee now your point, but what would be an example of an uncountable set wich is well-ordered?

Comment: @BCLC I don't know what or who is Sec27.

Comment: @raul section 27 of the book...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is nothing in the theorem or in the proof that forbids taking $B=[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$

$[0,1]$ is totally ordered, but not well-ordered (in the standard order). That forbids you from taking $B=[0,1]$.

The *definition* of well-order is that any non-empty subset has a *smallest element*. In other words, that any non-empty subset is bounded below and contains its own $\inf$. This is not the case for $[0,1]$.

I suggest you look up ordinals to see what well-orders look like; any well-ordered set is essentially (read: order isomorphic to) an ordinal. It's not so important for you to know and understand their (standard) *construction* at this stage, but see and learn how they're ordered.

The subset
$$
\{(i,b)\in \{1,2\}\times B\mid S_{(i,b)}\text{ is uncountable}\}\subseteq \{1,2\}\times B
$$
is non-empty, and therefore has a smallest element. It could be an element of the form $(1,b)$, or it could be $(2,0)$.

Comment: So, what is failing here is the "usual order". There must be another order $<'$ with wich $[0,\,1]$ is well ordered, right? Because the continuum hypothesis states that there is no set with cardinality between the cardinality of $\mathbb Z$ and the cardinality of $\mathbb R$, and the lemma talks about uncountable sets.

Comment: @raul If you assume the continuum hypothesis, then sure, there must be a bijection between the first uncountable ordinal and $[0,1]$, which gives a well-order on $[0,1]$. But such a well-order will have _nothing_ to do with the standard order. At all.

Comment: @Arthut I did not think we could "deny" (ignore?) the continuum hypothesis ... I thought this was independent of the axioms of set theory and we must take as true.

Comment: @raul That the continuum hypothesis ("CH") is independent of ZF set theory (and indeed of ZFC, which implies that $\Bbb R$ is well-orderable, but doesn't nail down how large it is compared to the ordinals) means _exactly_ that we can decide whichever way we want. We can take it as true, at which point our theory becomes "ZF + CH", we can take it as false, at which point our theory becomes "ZF + $\lnot$CH", or we can take it as undecideable, which is just ZF. Any popular science sourse who uses phrases like "true but unprovable" either don't know what they're doing, or oversimplify.

Comment: That is awesome! Where can I learn more about it?. Just remember I don't count with any help.

Comment: @raul I assume any graduate level textbook about set theory goes through this in excruciating detail. I personally used the first edition of Kenneth Kunen's "Set theory", but it's difficult to come by (I used the university library), and the second edition is not what I'd call an introductory text.

Comment: @ Thanks a lot. You have been very helpful